# Fill in blanks from the previous cell multiplied by the current cell in a different column in R

Tags: r, lag, dplyr, fill

I have the below data:

```
year<-c(2015:2030)
actual<-c(NA,NA,NA,3170.620936,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
delta<-c(0.276674282,
         0.23515258,
         0.133083622,
         0.236098022,
         0.399974342,
         0.385942573,
         0.165095681,
         0.163945346,
         0.155695778,
         0.147270755,
         0.146505261,
         0.133997582,
         0.123100693,
         0.119131947,
         0.115589755,
         0.103675414)

df<-cbind.data.frame(year,actual,delta)
df

   year   actual     delta
1  2015       NA 0.2766743
2  2016       NA 0.2351526
3  2017       NA 0.1330836
4  2018 3170.621 0.2360980
5  2019       NA 0.3999743
6  2020       NA 0.3859426
7  2021       NA 0.1650957
8  2022       NA 0.1639453
9  2023       NA 0.1556958
10 2024       NA 0.1472708
11 2025       NA 0.1465053
12 2026       NA 0.1339976
13 2027       NA 0.1231007
14 2028       NA 0.1191319
15 2029       NA 0.1155898
16 2030       NA 0.1036754
```

What I am trying to do is to replace NA's after the last valid data point multiplied by the current delta.  So, in this case, I want to multiply "actual" in 2016 by "delta" in 2017 and fill in the 2017 value for "actual".  I have tried the below code with no success:

```
df$actual_filled<-df$actual
df

library(dplyr)
df<-df%>%
  mutate( actual_filled=lag(actual_filled,1)*delta)
df

   year   actual     delta actual_filled
1  2015       NA 0.2766743            NA
2  2016       NA 0.2351526            NA
3  2017       NA 0.1330836            NA
4  2018 3170.621 0.2360980            NA
5  2019       NA 0.3999743      1268.167
6  2020       NA 0.3859426            NA
7  2021       NA 0.1650957            NA
8  2022       NA 0.1639453            NA
9  2023       NA 0.1556958            NA
10 2024       NA 0.1472708            NA
11 2025       NA 0.1465053            NA
12 2026       NA 0.1339976            NA
13 2027       NA 0.1231007            NA
14 2028       NA 0.1191319            NA
15 2029       NA 0.1155898            NA
16 2030       NA 0.1036754            NA
```

As you can see, the filling process ends in 2019.  I thought it would populate the new data till the end of the series.  The code I wrote is acting as if I am using the "actual" data, rather than "actual_filled".  Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works via a loop:

```
df$actual_filled<-df$actual
for (row in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(!is.na(df$actual_filled[row-1])) {
    df$actual_filled[row] <- df$delta[row] * df$actual_filled[row-1]
  }
}
```

I'm new to R so it may not be the best solution!